# Switch RAC nodes using dbconsole in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, failover, oracle-rac

Is it possible to use dbconsole (Enterprise Manager) to switch the active node of a Oracle 11gR2 cluster? The idea is to tell the active instance to go down and have another node take over.

I want to perform some failover testing and would like to see if the application under test follows but I am not sure what other ways to a brute-force shutdown of the active node's OS I have. Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: How about unplugging the network card on the active node?

Comment: That could be a plan C. Unfortunately I would have to run down into the server room to do that so it would be preferable for the majority of tests to have a remote possibility :-)

Comment: In my opinion the best method to emulate the server being offline/down is to pull the network cable. That ensures that there's no chance that the server could be contacted over the network via any means. If it means a walk to the server room, then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

For things where I don't want to be in the server room pulling power or network cables or disk controller cards and cables, I just stop the RAC node apps using software:

```
 srvctl stop nodeapps -n <nodename>
 srvctl stop listener -n <nodename>
 etc…
```

You could also stop the actual cluster services as well:

```
 crsctl stop resources
 crsctl stop crs
```